# Cross-sectional SUR in R

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, eviews

Is there a package in R that can estimate panel data with cross-sectional [seemingly unrelated regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seemingly_unrelated_regressions) generalized least squares weights (like in EViews)?

Comment: UCLA has a tutorial on how to implement an SUR in R with `systemfit` here: http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-perform-seemingly-unrelated-regression-in-r/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the "systemfit" package does that.