# Comparing regression coefficients between non-nested regression models

Tags: statistical-significance, econometrics, fixed-effects-model

I would like to evaluate whether two coefficients from regression models that are non-nested are statistically significantly different from one another. Specifically, I have models a) and b), where

a) $y_i$ = $\beta$$age_i$ + $id_i$

b) $y_i$ = $\beta$$age_i$ + $id_i$#$firm_f$

$age_i$ is a categorical variable for age, $id_i$ are individual fixed effects, $firm_f$ are firm fixed effects and $id_i$#$firm_f$ are the interaction of individual and firm fixed effects. That is, model b) uses only variation within each match of individual-firm. I want to test, whether $\beta$ estimated from a) is statistically significantly different from $\beta$ estimated from b) (for each category of $age_i$). I estimate these models using *reghdfe* in Stata.

Seeing whether confidence intervals of $\beta$'s overlap is not sufficient. But are also the formulas suggested for nested models e.g. in Clogg et al. (1995) non-applicable in this case? Is there a different formula for comparing coefficients from non-nested models? If so, the formula, references and possible Stata code would be much appreciated!

Clifford C. Clogg, Eva Petkova and Adamantios Haritou (1995). Statistical Methods for Comparing Regression Coefficients Between Models. *American Journal of Sociology*, Vol. 100, No. 5, pp. 1261-1293.

Comment: It's unclear just what model (b) represents. Are you including _only_ the interaction between firm and individual fixed effects while omitting the direct individual fixed effects and firm fixed effects? The two answers so far seem to differ on that. Including only the interaction terms is not generally a good idea. Are all combinations of individual and firm fixed effects possible, or are individuals nested within firms? How many individuals and firms are involved? Depending on those matters, your comparison might not be very easily interpretable in any event.

Comment: Are models a) and b) from different datasets or something? If not you DO have nested models, and the question can be simplified to a multivariate significance test.

Comment: As a point of notation, you shouldn't use the same coefficient parameter in models that are fundamentally different - as you're aware, adjusting for stuff changes the parameter's value *and* interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a test of statistical difference between non-nested models. Its usually recommended you use AIC (or something like that) but this is not a test of statistical significance. There are no agreed on ways to tell how far apart they are to matter although there are rules of thumb.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stata’s [suest](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/rsuest.pdf) for this type of test. I wrote [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/465215/264076) on how to do the same in `R`. It includes a link to data and Stata code for a reproducible example.